# In JavaScript, is it possible to only use .filter() to remove duplicates (the first instance is the one that is kept)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, duplicates

I have a straightforward solution for the problem:

```
function removeExtra(arr) {
  var args = [...arguments]
  .reduce(function(prev,curr){return prev.concat(curr)});
  var answer = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (answer.indexOf(args[i]) == -1)
        answer.push(args[i]);
  }
  return answer;
}

console.log(removeExtra([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]));
//-> Returns [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]
```

But, I'm trying to practice the logic of JavaScript's functional methods, in this case, `.filter()`. Is there a way to do it this way?

```
function removeExtra(arr) {
  return [...arguments]
  .reduce( (pre,cur) => pre.concat(cur) )
  //.filter( x => ??? );
}

console.log(removeExtra([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]));
//-> Should be [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]
```

## Edit 1:

As suggested, currently looking into `Set()`. This is the first time I encountered it. Be right back for research work!

## Edit 2:

BIG thanks to @Kaspars and @gcampbell for introducing `Set()` !!
I now have my solution:

```
function removeExtra(someArgs) {
  return [... new Set(
    [...arguments].reduce(function(prev,curr){
            return prev.concat(curr);
    })
  )]
}
```

This is just a minor revision to gcampbell's answer since I have to convert the `Set` back to an `Array` using `[... new Set()]`

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/a/14821032/670396

Comment: `new Set([...arguments].reduce( (pre,cur) => pre.concat(cur) )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for this.

```
function removeExtra() {
    const uniques = new Set();

    for(const array of ...arguments) {
        for(const element of array) {
            uniques.add(element);
        }
    }

    return Array.from(uniques);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the Big O Notations. What reference would you recommend for studying more about it?

Comment: @JohnPatrick Here's a ES6 reference to the Set structure http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-set.prototype.add It is implemented in a hashmap so its not lineral, but its also not in logarithmic time. Performance is faster, as Array.indexOf cannot benefit from this